# Can't move in map view swift

Tags: swift, dictionary, view, location

I can't move or zoom the map to other locations. I used this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qrdIL44T6FQ to show my location in the map. For some reason the map first zooms in very slowly (+- 30 seconds) to my location after opening the app. Then when I want to move around in the map I cant. It stays on my current location.

Here is my code:

```html
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class FirstViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
    
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        self.locationManager.delegate = self
        
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        
        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        
        self.mapView.showsUserLocation = true
        
        


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    
    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        
        let location = locations.last
        
        let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location!.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location!.coordinate.longitude)
        
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.5, longitudeDelta: 0.5 ))
        
        self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
        
        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    
    }
    
    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
        print("Errors: " + error.localizedDescription)
    }
        

}
```

Does anyone know the problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind I made a mistake somewhere. This code is working fine:

```html
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class FirstViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
    
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        self.locationManager.delegate = self
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        
        self.mapView.showsUserLocation = true
        
    }
    
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    
    // MARK: - Location Delegate Methods
    
    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])
    {
        let location = locations.last
        
        let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location!.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location!.coordinate.longitude)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 1, longitudeDelta: 1))
        
        self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
        
        self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }
    
    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError)
    {
        print("Error: " + error.localizedDescription)
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For those wondering what his mistake was:

He put `self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()` in the locationManager method instead of `self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation`.